# What is the largest size of creature that can be used as a weapon for Spellstrike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size, magus, improvised-weaponry

If a magus can wield a one-handed weapon, then they can use it with their Spellstrike ability.

And the larger a creature is, the larger their weapons can be.

Could a sufficiently large magus wield another living creature as a one-handed weapon, and then use that creature as a weapon for Spellstrike?

And if so, what is the largest size category of creature that can be used in this way?

Note that I'm not referring to the bladebound magus. For the purposes of this build, the wielded weapon has to be an actual creature and not an intelligent item.

I'm expecting more along the lines of a colossal dragon wielding another dragon, and using it to deliver *empowered shocking grasp*.

I realize that such a build is very inefficient, but I would like to know if such a build is possible. What race, size, and feats are required of both the magus and their "weapon"? Would the magus have to dip into other classes?

Comment: [Similar *D&D 3.5e* question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110041/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan So there's no way to take Weapon Focus (bear) ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think there's even a way to get even *proficiency* with, like, kobold or badger. (This, of course, assumes a to-be-weaponized creature is still alive—if it's dead, then it's likely an improvised weapons and all bets are off.)

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55203/throwing-things-and-people-as-weapons-how-would-this-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You (normally) cannot use a creature as a weapon

Creatures are not objects, nor weapons, nor their bodies are (officially) defined as objects when they are dead. [From Improvised Weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment-/weapons#TOC-Improvised-Weapons):

> **Improvised Weapons**
>
> Sometimes **objects** not crafted to be weapons nonetheless see use in combat. Because **such objects** are not designed for this use, any creature that uses an improvised weapon in combat is considered to be nonproficient with it and takes a –4 penalty on attack rolls made with that object. To determine the size category and appropriate damage for an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential to the weapon list to find a reasonable match. An improvised weapon scores a threat on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. An improvised thrown weapon has a range increment of 10 feet.

The feat [Throw Anything](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/throw-anything-combat-final/) simply removes the penalties of using an improvised weapon, but does not allow you to treat a creature as an object so it can be improvised as a weapon.

### Except for Body Bludgeon

The [Body Bludgeon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/body-bludgeon-ex) Rage Power allows you to use a creature as an *improvised weapon*, but the feat has a specific mechanic that deals a fixed amount of damage for each creature size (tiny 1d6, small 1d8, medium 1d10 and so on). The feat makes you believe that it progresses normally with the creature size, following the [Damage Dice Steps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27512/pathfinder-damage-dice-steps).

A large creature would cause 2d6 damage, a Huge creature would cause 2d6, a Gargantuan creature would cause 3d6, which is the maximum size category possible. Assuming you are big enough to be able to wield them as a weapon, which must be one size category smaller than you to be wielded as a two-handed weapon.

This means that the largest creature size you can wield as a weapon is a Gargantuan creature, assuming you are a Colossal creature yourself.

For *Spellstrike* to work, however, you will have to spend one turn casting your spell, and you cant cast with your off-hand because you are using both hands to wield the creature, then deliver it with a weapon attack on the next turn.

### Spellcasting and Rage

Normally, you cannot cast spells while raging, but there are ways that allow you to do so:

- The [Rage Prophet](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/apg/rage-prophet/) prestige class is able to cast some spells while in a rage.
- The [bloodrager](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/) class is able to cast bloodrager spells while in a bloodrage.
- The a bloodrager with the [Mad Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/mad-magic-combat/) feat will allow you to cast non-bloodrage spells while in your bloodrage.

Comment: If the weaponized dragon dead, is it an object now?

Comment: @aloisdg that is a question that nobody really has the answer. The system isnt prepared for a *yes* answer, nor some things make sense if the answer is *no*.